# Unable to read Src attribute from HTML String fomat

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a String as below

```
<iframe class = 'sproutvideo-player' src = '//videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/1c9adbb11d18e3c994/a5fd279ead76557c' width = '630' height = '354' frameborder = '0' allowfullscreen > < /iframe>
```

I am trying to read the attribute src from it .

I have tried as below

```
String html = "<iframe class = 'sproutvideo-player' src = '//videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/1c9adbb11d18e3c994/a5fd279ead76557c' width = '630' height = '354' frameborder = '0' allowfullscreen > < /iframe>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements links = doc.select("src");

         System.out.println(links.attr("src"));
```

could you please tell me how to read the src attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
 String html = "<iframe class = 'sproutvideo-player' src = '//videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/1c9adbb11d18e3c994/a5fd279ead76557c' width = '630' height = '354' frameborder = '0' allowfullscreen > < /iframe>";

 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
 Element link = doc.select("iframe").first();

 String linkHref = link.attr("src");
```

Remember that `select` method returns a list of all matching elements in the argument. For this purpose, I have used `.first()` here.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 Elements links = doc.select("src");
```

to

```
 Elements links = doc.select("iframe");
```